# Modify string phone number with regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I am pretty new to regex and had a quick question about using it. I have a phone number as a string and I need to remove all the special characters and just leave the numbers. for example if the number is

(555) 555-5555

I would like to have the result be 5555555555

Can I use regex to accomplish this is java?

Answer (score 4):

```
String ph = "(555) 555-5555";
ph = ph.replaceAll("\\D","");
```

`\\D` is the short for a non-digit. So we replace every non-digit in the string with nothing, effectively deleting them.

Comment: Thanks... could you maybe explain what \\D denotes in regex so I can just learn what it's actually doing?